# PHP - Change '1' generated with date('N'); to 'Monday'?

Tags: php, date

I have used PHP's `date('N')` function to turn the current date into the day number of the week (like 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday ...), I would like to change the '1' into 'Monday' after retrieving it from my database. Any idea on how to change the '1' into 'Monday' or '2' into 'Tuesday'..?

Comment: What have you tried? Also: Take a look at [PHPs Array docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Why dont you just use date('l')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to do array map for days

```
    $weekDays=array(1=>'Mon', 2=>'Tue', 3=>'Wed', 4=>'Thu', 5=>'Fri', 6=>'Sat', 7=>'Sun');
    echo $weekDays[date('N')]
```

[Online Example](http://ideone.com/4gTeux)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date('D');
```

It returns the textual representation of the day (Mon ... Sun).